# Facebook debugger (and social plugins) giving Website Inaccessible error

Tags: html, facebook-social-plugins

we've recently started having problems with facebook in that the comments plugin stopped working properly, showing the error 'url inaccessible' on newly created pages.

We checked the url debugger and it appears every page on our website except the homepage brings back the 'website inaccessible' error. We've checked tags, character encoding etc but have had no luck, so any help will be much appreciated.

As an example - here is the homepage via the debugger:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.netweather.tv%2F

Here is another page (which is live and accessible, but is giving the error):

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.netweather.tv%2Findex.cgi%3Faction%3Dnews%3Bstoryid%3D842%3Bsess%3D

And just to make things a bit weirder, we've spotted that any address with a query string also comes back as inaccessible. (sorry can't put more than 2 urls in)

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the semicolon in your url! That's legal, but *propably* not the best practice in your case and it is most likely the reason for your url inaccessible error too!

Instead use `&` to seperate values!

Comment: Thanks, although even pages without ; are coming back as inaccessible:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.netweather.tv%2Findex.cgi%3F12345